# What is the order of loading the CSS files in a HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I want to know the order of loading the CSS files in a HTML page.

My actual requirement is like this: I have more than 10 CSS files in my application.

I am importing some 3 to 4 CSS files in each HTML page. The problem is I have duplicate classes that defined in some CSS files. That means I override some of the CSS classes in the CSS files. 
In some pages it behaves correctly. In some pages it behaves wrongly. I have inline styles defined for some of the DIVs in HTML page also. I am keeping CSS class for that DIVs also.

Can anyone know which one will take higher priority or which one loads first ?

Comment: Apart from all the great answers you had you could also consider joining up all those files, set up a PHP file that does it (readfile for ex.) and serve it as a single one to the client. Both the server and the user will thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Generally the last rule takes precedence. With that being said, there are "exceptions" in that inline styles take precedence over external stylesheets ( an inline !important is more important than an external !important, etc ), and more specific selectors override generic selectors.

Read all about it @ http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Comment: Ok, how the external file loading will be ? Is it depends on size of the CSS file, name or any other parameter ?

Comment: The external files are loaded the order they are included in the DOM, and imported stylesheets before the 'importer'.

Answer (score 18):

CSS files are loaded in the order that they appear in the page. If a class is redefined in a CSS file, it will override the previous class statements.

So
`div.sample { background: none; width: 200px }`
and
`div.sample { color: #FFF; width: 400px }`
will become
`div.sample { background: none; color: #FFF; width: 400px }`

You can also use the '!important' addin to make rules take precedence over other defined rules.

So
`div.sample { background: none; width: 200px !important }`
and
`div.sample { color: #FFF; width: 400px }`
will become
`div.sample { background: none; color: #FFF; width: 200px !important }`

**Note:** Many people will advise *against* using the '!important' addin in your CSS files. Personally, I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: While there's nothing inherently wrong with !important, a problem arises when it's used unnecessarily; it makes it more difficult to override styles (simply creating a new rule that appears later or is more specific will provide more flexibility). It's not hard to get into the "!important wars" where attributes are littered with !important because different (lazy) developers are trying to override each others rules. The w3c's main motivation for !important was to give users an easy way to override author style sheets.

Answer (score 3):

Each element will be rendered based on the properties from the last style-sheet from which it has been selected.  Properties which have been declared as `!important;` are an exception.  Part of the problem is that you have 10 style-sheets.