# Reset all CSS for one element and its children

Tags: html, css

My Problem:

We offer full customization for our site to our customers (so they can make out app look like the rest of there site). They provide us a HTML "surround" page, which our main app is rendered into (no iFrame, the HTML of our app is string.replaced() server side essentially). They can include any JS and CSS links to style this "surround" page.

The problem is, they often include their main CSS file for there full website (totally unnecessary, but easiest method to make there part look right), which includes lots of generic rules. Our app then obviously then obeys these rules, and it breaks a lot of our default styles. Specific example, they have a 'h3' rule which sets text-transform and font-family

```
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One',sans-serif;
}
```

In our own CSS, we set a the font-family of a class that is applied to the h3 tag, but not the text-transform property. As such, our CSS changes the font-family, but we inherit the text-transform.

Is there any way I can tell the browser to "start again" with applying CSS from a given element? I know its very un-Cascading, but I need the users CSS to stop cascading past our apps first element, and then apply our CSS to that element and its children. I hope i've explained myself clearly.

Comment: You can load your `css` last

Comment: What do you mean by "cascading past our apps first element"? What is a "first element"?

Comment: @Tesseract Our CSS is loaded last, the problem is we don't specify a rule for "text-transform", so it uses the first one it finds, which is their CSS.

Comment: @Terry our "first element" is the first HTML element of our app, its an angular2 app so its out first component.

Comment: you can change the order of the css, first apply their CSS and then apply yours so only your important css will overide theirs main css other properties will be load from their.

Comment: Then specify your own `text-transform` so that whatever `text-transform` they use will be overwritten by yours

Comment: @Tesseract I specified a text-transform for our first element, but their h3 rule is more specific than my inherited rule, so it takes precedence over mine. Specifying a reset for every single element is not possible, because some of out elements use inheritance from there parent elements.

Comment: @eirenaios As i said, this is already how its down, and its not working because we don't specify a text-transform rule but they do.

Comment: @Matthew Peel then you can override/reset them using **text-transform:none or initial** in your style

Comment: @eirenaios I'm aware, but I don't want to have to re-write our CSS every time we get a new customer. I was hoping for a straight forward solution.

Comment: When you let users add their own CSS like that, there is no such thing as a straight forward solution. A possibility is to isolate your CSS using [`CSS :scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope), though it has limited browser support

Comment: So until then `:scope` is a reality, you need to make sure your rules are applied last, always has higher specificity and you might even have to use `!important` as well

Comment: Indeed. If you do allow any CSS in the parent, including `!important`, you may have no choice but to resort to `!important` yourself. I assume that using an iframe is not an option?

Comment: @LGSon I did find scope, but I wasn't sure it would work (easily), since as far as I can tell I need to add the namespace to every single HTML element in my app, i cant just give a name to my root element.

Comment: @MrLister This is what I was thinking, i'm going to end up writing some JS to fix this I can tell. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1:**

Give them a class like `remove-all-styles`

```
  .remove-all-styles {
        all: revert;
   }
```

Then write your css code below this css code and make sure your css has higher priority than their css file.

***[What is the order of loading the CSS files in a HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067455/what-is-the-order-of-loading-the-css-files-in-a-html-page)***

**Option 2:**

Give initial or auto values to all elements in css then write your css code below

***https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp***

Comment: unfortunately this isn't supported widely enough yet to be useful. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all

Comment: @andi Ya ,I provided another option though I don't like that option, too much typing  **:(** .

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything for me.