# How to make html pull from local .css file?

Tags: html

So my good friend lent me his resume template. The problem is it goes to his unpkg link to get the minified css file. Everytime I alter the css file, it is overwritten by the one being fetched. I am looking to make the local css file the main source for the website structure.
Sorry for formatting in advanced, still not great with it.

```
**HTML**

 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>resume</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,200,700" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-resume@1.0.1/resume.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-resume@1.0.1/resume.min.js"></script>


</div>
</head><body ng-app="Resume" ng-cloak="">
    <resume>
        <resume-heading first-name="example"
                        last-name="example"
                        linkedin="example"
                        github="example"
                        email="example">
        </resume-heading>
        <resume-body>
            <resume-column flex="20">
                <sidebar-category name="Education">
                    <p>University At Albany Student</p>
                    <p>Graduating May 2021</p>
                    <p>Computer Engineering </p>
                    <p>Computer Science</p>
                    <p>GPA - 3.01</p>
                </sidebar-category>
                <sidebar-category name="Achievements">
                    <p>FIRST Robotics championships 2015,2016,2017</p>
                    <p>Lead Electrical Captain 2016,2017</p>
                    <p>Advanced Regents Diploma</p>
                </sidebar-category>
                <sidebar-category name="Coursework">
                    <p>Data Structures</p>
                    <p>Algorithms</p>
                    <p>Programmings Langauges</p>
                    <p>Discrete Math</p>
                </sidebar-category>
            </resume-column>
            <resume-column flex="80">
                <category name="Professional Experience">
                    <category-item title="High School Jobs" subtitle="Brinkmann Hardware">
                        <li>Local Hardware Store work</li>
                        <li>Cashier, store clerk</li>
                    </category-item>
                </category>
                <category name="Projects">
                </category>
                <category name="Skills">
                    <category-item title="Web Development">
                        <li><strong>Dank Memes</strong> I can find the deepest, dankest memes out there on the inerwebs</li>
                        <li><strong>Distributed Systems</strong> I only run my apps on Kubernetes and a CoreOS cluster</li>
                        <li><strong>Tooling</strong> I literally treat Dan Abromov's Twitter as holy gospel</li>
                        <li><strong>Frameworks</strong> React, Redux, Reselect, Redankmeme, Revenant, Angular</li>
                    </category-item>
                    <category-item title="Technologies">
                        <li><strong>Experienced With</strong> Web &amp; Hybrid App Development \ Functional Programming</li>
                        <li><strong>Programming</strong> Javascript \ Scala \ Python \ PHP \ C \ Java</li>
                        <li><strong>Databases</strong> RethinkDB \ MongoDB \ MySQL \ PostgreSQL \ Redis</li>
                    </category-item>
                </category>
            </resume-column>
        </resume-body>
    </resume>


</body></html>

**js**



 angular.module('Resume', ['ngMaterial'])
.component('resume', {
  transclude: true,
  template: `<div class="resume">
    <section class="main" ng-transclude></section>
  </div>`
})

.component('resumeHeading', {
  controllerAs: 'r',
  transclude: true,
  bindings: {
    firstName: '@',
    lastName: '@',
    website: '@',
    phone: '@',
    email: '@',
    github: '@',
    linkedin: '@'
  },
  template: `<div class="header">
    <div class="page-title-container">
      <h1 class="page-title page-title-first">{{r.firstName}}</h1>
      <h1 class="page-title page-title-last">{{r.lastName}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-icons">
      <a ng-if="r.website" class="md-subhead page-subhead" ng-href="https://{{r.website}}" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-code"></i>{{r.website}}
      </a>
      <span ng-if="r.phone" class="md-subhead page-subhead">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-phone"></i>{{r.phone}}
      </span>
      <a ng-if="r.email" class="md-subhead page-subhead" ng-href="mailto:{{r.email}}" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope"></i>{{r.email}}
      </a>
      <a ng-if="r.github" class="md-subhead page-subhead" ng-href="https://github.com/{{r.github}}" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-github"></i>{{r.github}}
      </a>
      <a ng-if="r.linkedin" class="md-subhead page-subhead" ng-href="https://linkedin.com/in/{{r.linkedin}}" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin-square"></i>{{r.linkedin}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>`
})

.component('resumeBody', {
  transclude: true,
  template: `<div layout="row" ng-transclude></div>`
})

.component('resumeColumn', {
  transclude: true,
  template: `<div ng-transclude></div>`
})

.component('sidebarCategory', {
  controllerAs: 'r',
  bindings: {
    name: '@'
  },
  transclude: true,
  template: `<div flex="" class="category-row">
    <div class="category">
      <h5 class="category-row-title">{{r.name}}</h5>
      <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    </div>
  </div>`
})

.component('category', {
  controllerAs: 'r',
  bindings: {
    name: '@'
  },
  transclude: true,
  template: `<div flex="" class="category-row">
    <h4 class="category-row-title">{{r.name}}</h4>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </div>`
})

.component('categoryItem', {
  controllerAs: 'r',
  bindings: {
    title: '@',
    subtitle: '@'
  },
  transclude: true,
  template: `<div class="category">
    <h5 class="category-title md-body-2">{{r.title}}</h5>&nbsp;
    <h5 class="category-subtitle md-caption">{{r.subtitle}}</h5>
    <ul class="category-bullets" ng-transclude></ul>
  </div>`
})

**css**



 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, li, span {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.resumeBody {
  background-color: #a1eac8;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.resume .main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.resume .main .header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
.resume .main .header .page-title-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.resume .main .header .page-title {
  font-size: 48pt;
  display: inline;
}
.resume .main .header .page-title-first {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.resume .main .header .page-title-last {
  font-weight: 200;
}
.resume .main .header .header-icons {
  text-align: center;
}
.resume .main .header .header-icons .page-subhead {
  margin: 1rem 15px;
  display: inline;
}
.resume .main .header .fa {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.resume .main .indented {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.resume .main .category-row {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.resume .main .category-row .category {
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.resume .main .category-row .category-row-title {
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}

.resume .main .category-row .category-title,
.resume .main .category-row .category-subtitle {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.resume .main .category-row .category-bullets {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.resume .main .category-row p,
.resume .main .category-row li {
  font-size: smaller;
}

sidebar-category:last-of-type .category {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

category:last-of-type category-item:last-of-type .category {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

a.page-subhead {
  color: initial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Where are you loading the local CSS file? Am I missing something?

Comment: I see multiple CSS files being included. What CSS file are you talking about? You also need to add `<script>` tags to your CSS in your HTML. The way you currently have it you would end up with a bunch of text at the bottom when you scroll down that is all intending to be CSS stuff.

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Then your example does not reflect reality. That makes helping you extremely difficult. Please read the links I posted above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the order of loading the CSS files in a HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067455/what-is-the-order-of-loading-the-css-files-in-a-html-page)

Comment: I figured it out for anyone who stumbles upon this with a similar issue: I had to change the script and linking in the HTML to match my css and js files accordingly. Thanks for the suggestions to everyone who offered but I just had to look through it.

Comment: @FrankFiumara, I'm happy you resolved this. But, no one is going to benefit from this unless you explain exactly what happened. I can make some assumptions, and I'd probably be correct that your path was incorrect, but you didn't include anything in your example to indicate what the path to your files is or that you were even trying to include local files within your html - there's no inclusion of local files in your html. I would suggest editing this post to make it more complete so you get used to doing so when you post your next question.